# LiveUSB will not Boot on Lenovo v570

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, lenovo, live-cd

I have a Lenovo v570 that I'm trying to do a clean install of trusty on and for the life of me I can't find any way to get it working.

When I try to boot from the SD card it's on, it doesn't even list it in the boot menu.

I installed it from 'Startup Disk Creator' from another device with trusty but still no luck. I've heard that there are a lot of problems with UEFI, which I'm guessing is the issue here but when I go into the BIOS, it mentions nothing about UEFI.

I've tried different USB sticks, SD cards, DVDs, and CDs but still no luck. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the boot device order in your BIOS?

Comment: Yes, the USB stick is first before the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your computer does not support UEFI - there's a lot of reporting around troubles with installing on the v570, but it looks like some people found a solution back in 2012 - [this might be what you need to do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107193/cant-boot-ubuntu-on-lenovo-v570)